# Problems using Pandas.date_range with monthly frequency

Tags: python, pandas

I am having problems creating a series of monthly dates using Panda’s date_range.
When I use:

```
import pandas as pd
offset = pd.DateOffset(months=3)
pd.bdate_range(dt.datetime(2018, 11, 30), periods=4, freq=offset, name='projected_date')
```

I get the following dates:

```
['2018-11-30', '2019-02-28', '2019-05-28', '2019-08-28']
```

However, I want to get the following dates:

```
['2018-11-30', '2019-02-28', '2019-05-30', '2019-08-30']
```

It seems like the February date screws up all the subsequent dates.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems like you want a given day in a series of months likely for some type of monthly time series). Is there any rationale or logic for why you need a given day of the month? *For example, I need the last day of the month unless it's a holiday or a weekend, in which case I need the previous day.*

Rather than manually specifying an offset you should use the built in date times in the pandas [datetime module](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases). In this case `CustomBusinessDays` could be used to define some type of custom business month and then write a snippet of code such that

```
 customcalendar = ['2012-05-01', datetime(2013, 5, 1), np.datetime64('2014-05-01')]
 newCal= CustomBusinessDay(holidays=customcalendar)
 pd.bdate_range(pd.datetime(2018, 11, 30), periods=4, freq=customcalendar,...)
```

Comment: This type of logic is often used to project future payments in finance.

Comment: Are you looking at bonds on a 30/360 schedule?